# form.setRequireLogin() giving error Script error message: Exception: This operation is not supported

Tags: google-apps-script

Quite new in the apps script world. Trying to create *"google form generator"* with dynamically created questions/attachment.

All worked well until I noticed that whenever I create the form, users have to "sign in by google account". This was not requested so I found *setRequreLogin()*.

Whatever I set (false or true) I receive the error: *"Script error message: Exception: This operation is not supported"*

I did some googleing around and it seems the solution is to have the *"google suite gmail account"*.
I use my personal **@gmail.com** email.
Do anybody have got the same error?
Or is there anybody who is not having the same error using the *"regular"* gmail?

How I do it (because it might be a bit different than default):

1. I use python to execute function that is created in appscript
2. The apps script had to be linked to *"standard GCP project"* otherwise I would not be able to execute from python (external API call)
3. I publish the apps script *"deploy as API executable"* so I can execute (and pass couple of parameters) the script from Python

Thanks for help

```
function createForm(ordernumber,surname, country, data_list) {
var form = FormApp.create(ordernumber);


form.setTitle(ordernumber +" | " + surname)
    .setDescription('anything')
    .setConfirmationMessage('you are welcome...');
//    .setAllowResponseEdits(true)
//    .setLimitOneResponsePerUser(true)
//      .requiresLogin(false);
      .setRequireLogin(true);
//    .setAcceptingResponses(true);

}
```

Comment: You may want to give more details, preferably with code examples explaining your context.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using as well?

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş is it better?

Answer (score 0):

According to the `setRequireLogin()` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setrequireloginrequirelogin):

> `setRequireLogin()` - Sets whether the form requires respondents to log in to an account in the same domain or a subdomain before responding. The default for new forms is false unless a domain administrator changes the default.
>
> **This feature is available only for forms created by Google Workspace users. Users of other types of Google accounts can't be required to log in.**

Therefore, if you posses a **gmail** account, you cannot use this method.

However, since your script is creating a new form, the users who use this API executable will have to authorize this operation, hence the login screen they are receiving.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Form Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setrequireloginrequirelogin).

Comment: Thanks. but I dont get the last sentence.

I am having the same account access from python, that is calling the API (that is on the same google account). What do you mean "authorize"? Can I authorize it somehow upfront?

Or is there a way to generate form link, that is not requiring the "google account login"?

Comment: No, there is no way to authorize upfront and the authorization requires a google account login.